# Django ORM filter records between last month 15th date to current month 15th date

Tags: python, django, orm, python-datetime

I want to filter the queryset records from the previous month's 15th date to the current month 15th.

Does someone have any idea how to do it?

> Models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

> Views.py

```
class BookView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwags):
        start_date = '15th_of_previous_month'
        end_date = '15th_of_current_month'
        qs = Book.objects.filter(created_on__gte=start_date,created_on__lt=end_date)
        ...
```

Comment: Query seems to be correct, did you face any error with this one?

Comment: @ans2human: likely `15th_of_previous_month` will not be parsed. These are "placeholders" for actual code I think.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem basically a months data from current date! got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the 15th of the current month with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

this_month_15 = now().date().replace(day=15)
```

Calculating the previous month can be done by subtracting 15 days, and then again replace the `day` parameter with `15`:

```
from datetime import timedelta

prev_month_15 = (this_month_15 - timedelta(days=15)).replace(day=15)
```

Comment: I did something similar to it but the problem is it will work only when month has 30 days. What if month has 28, 29, or 31 days? In that case prev_month_15 won't be 15th actually.

Comment: @ShahidTariq: why do you expect this only to work for months with 30 days? By subtracting 15 days, we get the last day of the previous month (regardless the number of days). Then we set the days on 15, thus obtain the 15th of the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

> This is how I try to solve it:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)  # first date of current month
previous_month_date = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)  # this will be the last day of previous month
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(previous_month_date.year) + '-' + str(previous_month_date.month) + '-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = first + datetime.timedelta(days=15)
qs = Book.objects.filter(created_on__gte=start_date,created_on__lt=end_date)
```